# Speed up Deep Learning Inference without batching samples?

Tags: python, tensorflow, scikit-learn, deep-learning

For algorithmic reasons, I would like to perform inference sequentially, sample by sample instead of performing a batched sample. It is Deep Neuronal network with the following structure:

```
Model: "sequential"
_________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
 dense (Dense)               (None, 64)                2624      
                                                                 
 dense_1 (Dense)             (None, 128)               8320      
                                                                 
 dense_2 (Dense)             (None, 128)               16512     
                                                                 
 dense_3 (Dense)             (None, 1)                 129       
                                                                 
=================================================================
Total params: 27585 (107.75 KB)
Trainable params: 27585 (107.75 KB)
Non-trainable params: 0 (0.00 Byte)
_________________________________________________________________
None
```

My testing shows that the batched inference is considerably faster (1.34 seconds):

```py
start = time.time()
y_pred = model.predict(x_test_feature_space)
end = time.time()
print("Exeuction time: ", end - start)
print("Execution time per sample: ", (end-start)/len(x_test_feature_space))

# 672/672 [==============================] - 1s 1ms/step
# Exeuction time:  1.345379114151001
# Execution time per sample:  6.26194607470794e-05
```

Whereas, the sequential, sample by sample inference is very slow (24 minutes):

```py
y_pred = []
timings = []

start_total = time.time()
for x in x_test_feature_space:
    start = time.time()
    y_pred.append(model.predict(np.array([x,]), verbose=False))
    end = time.time()
    timings.append(end-start)
end_total = time.time()

print("Exeuction time: ", end_total - start_total)
print("Average time per sample: ", sum(timings)/len(timings))

# Exeuction time:  1467.2437105178833
# Average time per sample:  0.06825089837496631
```

Seeing this contrast, makes me believe the inference cost is lower than simply loading up the model.

Is there any approach I could investigate to improve the timing of sequential (sample by sample) inference? What are the best practices?

Comment: It is known fact. If you inference with many samples, use `mode.predict(x)` and if you have one sample to infernce, just call the model like `y_out=model(x)`.

Comment: For references. https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/40261#issuecomment-647191650

Comment: Soliciting opinions in general and specifically on best practices is considered off topic.  Please review the rules and guidelines before asking questions.  https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/142353/why-is-asking-a-question-on-best-practice-a-bad-thing/142354#142354